# Not understanding this cover version

Tags: transcription

let's take this song:

I can hear a progression of Em-G-D-C-G-D

but when I look at this cover:

(obviously the guitar is tuned down)

I can see him play F5-G5#-G5-C5#-G5#-G5
if you account for the tuning, that would work out to:
E5-G5-F5#-C5-G5-F5#

so he's playing a F# where I hear a D; assuming we forget about the 3rd, the only difference is that he has a C# where I have a D, in the 5th.

now, when I try to play it with a F# chord it really doesn't sound good but that's what I see in the video.

can anyone clarify this? :) I feel confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree in the original there is D with F# in the bass. It's similar to a regular power chord with 1 fret wider fretting hand stretch.

The cover sounds OK because:

- The guitar is rather quiet in comparison to the original track
- In the verse only root notes are played, not full chords
- F#5 might be interpreted as third and major seventh of D, so kind of fits

Note there are some other details omitted in the cover version as well.